# Conditional within Jenkins `tool` block

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline

We use Jenkins shared libraries and need to support the ability of individual repositories to override the default JDK. We have added `OpenJDK-20` and `OpenJDK-11` in Jenkins > Manage Jenkins as available JDKs alongside the default JDK 8. Now, how can I [express this conditional within the `tools` block](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/syntax/#tools)?

Current pipeline definition (`debug_pipeline.groovy`):

```
// Jenkins declarative pipeline for debugging Jenkins agent

def call (body) {
    def pipelineParams= [:]
    body.resolveStrategy = Closure.DELEGATE_FIRST
    body.delegate = pipelineParams
    body()

    pipeline {
        agent any
        options {
            // Prepend all console output generated by the
            // Pipeline run with the time at which the line was emitted
            timestamps()
        }
        tools {
            // Define tools to auto-install and put on the PATH
            // The tool name must be pre-configured in Jenkins under Manage Jenkins → Tools.
            maven 'apache-maven-3.9.3'
            jdk 'OpenJDK-20'
        }
        stages {
            stage('Initialize') {
                steps {
                    hello(pipelineParams.greeting)
                }
            }
            stage('Debug') {
                steps {
                    sh 'command -v java && java -version'
                    sh 'command -v mvn && mvn -version'
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Now, I would *like* for the use of JDK 11 or 20 to be optional by having projects use pipeline parameters to specify them. I have tried:

```
        tools {
            if (pipelineParams.maven != 'system') {
                maven pipelineParams.maven
            }
            if (pipelineParams.jdk != 'system') {
                jdk pipelineParams.jdk
            }
        }
```

And the invoking repository's `Jenkinsfile`:

```
@Library('pipeline-library') _

debug_pipeline {
    Greeting = 'Goodbye'
    jdk = 'OpenJDK-20'
    maven = 'apache-maven-3.9.3'
}
```

However, this errors with `debug_pipeline.groovy: 15: Expected to find ‘someTool "someVersion"’`. It also seems that I cannot use `when` within `tools`.

So, how can I effectively allow projects to override the JDK using pipeline parameters?

Comment: It would probably be easier and fix the issue if you declared the values as parameters with default values instead.

Comment: @MattSchuchard how would overriding the defaults work?

Comment: Either as global var method parameter inputs, pipeline parameter inputs, or both.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right in stating that `tool {}` does not allow you to make tool inclusions conditional (within the curly brackets).

The best way to fix/solve this is to add a default directly inside of `def pipelineParams = [:]`; these defaults will be overridden by the input of your Jenkinsfile (`debug_pipeline {...}`). This is done because you specified: `body.resolveStrategy = Closure.DELEGATE_FIRST`, `body.delegate = pipelineParams` and `body()` inside of `def call (body) {}`. Example:

- vars/debug_pipeline.groovy

```
def call (body) {
    def pipelineParams = [
         'GREETINGS' : 'Hi!'
         'JDK'       : 'OpenJDK-20',
         'MAVEN'     : 'apache-maven-3.9.3'
    ]
    body.resolveStrategy = Closure.DELEGATE_FIRST
    body.delegate = pipelineParams
    body()
    ...
}
```

- Jenkinsfile

```
@Library('pipeline-library') _

debug_pipeline {
    JDK    = 'OpenJDK-11'
    MAVEN  = 'apache-maven-3.8.8'
    CHEESE = 'GOUDA'
}
```

Would Result in:

```
pipelineParams == [
     'GREETINGS' : 'Hi!'
     'JDK'       : 'OpenJDK-11',
     'MAVEN'     : 'apache-maven-3.8.8'
     'CHEESE'    : 'GOUDA'
]
```

Considering you are using a [pipeline library](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/shared-libraries/), you might even create a *"helper"* class (inside of src) and centralize tool versions. This is really helpful if you have multiple pipelines or many versions of a tool; So only the helper class *has* to change and not all pipelines and Jenkinsfiles. Example:

- src/com/corp/lib/EnvironmentHelper.groovy

```
package com.corp.lib

class EnvironmentHelper implements Serializable {
    public static final String JDK_11 = 'OpenJDK-11'
    public static final String JDK_20 = 'OpenJDK-20'
    public static final String DEFAULT_JDK = JDK_11
}
```

**This allows you to use**:

- vars/debug_pipeline.groovy

```
import com.corp.lib.EnvironmentHelper
def call (body) {
    def pipelineParams = [
         'JDK'       : EnvironmentHelper.DEFAULT_JDK,
         ...
    ]
    ...
}
```

- Jenkinsfile

```
@Library('pipeline-library') _
import com.corp.lib.EnvironmentHelper

debug_pipeline {
    JDK  = EnvironmentHelper.JDK_20
    ...
}
```